# Is there a specified Ray object in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, ray-picking

Im doing some work using ray-picking in a DirectX project and I just wondered whether there was an actual 'ray' object type? (rather than just storing direction/origin variables)

I know I could create something like

```
struct ray
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 direction
    D3DXVECTOR3 origin
};
```

but does anything already exist?  Im currently working in DX9 but I am open to answers in newer versions of DirectX.

Comment: Nothing in the SDK. Make one yourself or find one online. Use `DirectXMath` for math helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use legacy D3DXmath, you should consider [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx), although that library also just takes an origin position and a direction vector to represent a ray for the `BoundingSphere`, `BoundingBox`, `BoundingOrientedBox`, and `BoundingFrustum` classes and the `TriangleTests` namespace

```
bool Intersects( _In_ FXMVECTOR Origin, _In_ FXMVECTOR Direction, _Out_ float& Dist ) const;
```

See the [DirectXMath Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415571.aspx) on MSDN, particularly [Working with D3DXMath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729728.aspx)

You can also use the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), which has a `Ray` class defined.